# Lower volume of certain audio on frame with multiple audios. AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, streaming, volume, mute

Okay, so, here's the deal, i have a sound steaming from an URL since the first frame (60 total), and i added another sound file (from the library) to a certain frame. As expected, both sounds overlapp, so i decided to make a mute function... the problem is, i cant get it to apply only to the streaming audio, the function mutes all audio, and i cant use the variable mySound because the mute function needs to be on other keyframe to work...

Here's the code of the streaming audio:

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var lastPosition:Number = 0;// pause button
mySound.load(new URLRequest("http://trollfacequiz.16mb.com/MusicFiles/Goat%20Songs.mp3"));
//mySound.play();
SoundMixer.stopAll();
myChannel = mySound.play();

btn_mute.btn_pause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPause);
btn_mute.btn_play.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPlay);

function onClickPause(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    btn_mute.btn_pause.visible = false;
    lastPosition = myChannel.position;
    myChannel.stop();
}

function onClickPlay(e:MouseEvent):void
{
        btn_mute.btn_pause.visible = true;
        myChannel = mySound.play(lastPosition);
}
```

And the mute function:

```
function setVolume(vol){
var volTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
volTransform.volume = vol;
SoundMixer.soundTransform = volTransform;
}

setVolume(0);
```

Comment: you need to apply the `SoundTransform` on the appropriate `myChannel` instead of on `SoundMixer`

Comment: Thanks! Thats what i've been missing! Such a silly mistake...